# How to close div IF another's opening

Tags: jquery, if-statement, jquery-animate

EDIT: Updated wording due to complete lack of replies.

***Description***:

**Left** DIV slides out when the ***LEFT*** button is clicked.

**Right** DIV slides out when the ***RIGHT*** button is clicked.

***Problem***:

If the **Left** DIV is **out** and the ***RIGHT*** button is clicked **>>>** Slide **Left** DIV **in** and slide **Right** DIV **out**.

If the **Right** DIV is **out** and the ***LEFT*** button is clicked **>>>** Slide **Right** DIV **in** and slide **Left** DIV **out**.

*Help is much appreciated.*

```
$("#left").click(function () {
    if (out === 0) {
        $("#left-slide").animate({
            width: "400px"
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 1900
        });
        out = 1;
    } else {
        $("#left-slide").animate({
            width: "0px"
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 2000
        });
        out = 0;
    }
});

     $("#right").click(function () {
    if (out === 0) {
        $("#right-slide").animate({
            width: "400px"
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 1900
        });
        out = 1;
    } else {
        $("#right-slide").animate({
            width: "0px"
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 2000
        });
        out = 0;
    }
});
```

Here's jsFiddle with full code: http://jsfiddle.net/fxVS9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/fxVS9/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var l_out = 0;
    var r_out = 0;

    $("#left").click(function () {
        if (l_out === 0) {
            $("#left-slide").animate({
                width: "400px"
            }, {
                queue: false,
                duration: 1900
            });
            l_out = 1;
        } else {
            $("#left-slide").animate({
                width: "0px"
            }, {
                queue: false,
                duration: 2000
            });
            l_out = 0;
        }
        $("#right-slide").animate({
                width: "0px"
            }, {
                queue: false,
                duration: 2000
            });
            r_out = 0;
    });

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a compact version.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#left,#right").click(function () {
              var clickedDiv = $(this).attr('id');
              var nonclickDiv = (clickedDiv === "left") ? "right" : "left";
              var currDiv = $('#' + clickedDiv + "-slide");
              var offDiv =  $('#' + nonclickDiv + "-slide" );
        currDiv.animate({
            width: currDiv.width() > 0 ? "0px" : "400px"
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 1900
       });
       offDiv.animate({
            width: "0px"
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 2000
       });
   });
 });
```

Hope you like (and accept :-) ) lol. yeah rep.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, this works like charm. Though I must say the second solution suits my needs better as there's a lot more code for each slide. I do like the compact version, will try to implement that. Appreciate your help.